# symfony 2.1 date don't persist after usage of ->modify method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a problem with Symfony 2.1 and persisting dates to database. I use PHP 5.3. My code is as followes:

```
public function moveAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $id = $request->get('id');
        $daydelta = $request->get('daydelta');
        $minutedelta = $request->get('minutedelta');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MedSystemTimetableBundle:Appointment')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Appointment entity.');
        }

            if (0 != $daydelta) {

            $day = ($daydelta > 0) ? '+'.$daydelta : $daydelta;
            $day .= (abs($daydelta) == 1) ? ' day' : ' days';

            $modifyFrom = $entity->getTimeFrom()->modify($day);
            $modifyTo = $entity->getTimeTo()->modify($day);

            $entity->setTimeFrom($modifyFrom);
            $entity->setTimeTo($modifyTo);
        }
        if (0 != $minutedelta) {

            $month = ($minutedelta > 0) ? '+'.$minutedelta : $minutedelta;
            $month .= (abs($minutedelta) == 1) ? ' minute' : ' minutes';

            $modifyFrom = $entity->getTimeFrom()->modify($month);
            $modifyTo = $entity->getTimeTo()->modify($month);        

            $entity->setTimeFrom($modifyFrom);
            $entity->setTimeTo($test);
        }

        $em->flush();

        return new Response('ok', 200);
    }
```

I have dumped the new values of times and it changes correctly, but for some reason it doesn't save to database. But if I set the value to new \DateTime it works just fine. Any ideas for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Why you aren't using `gedmo` `timestampable` doctrine extensions? It goes automatic with event listener on persist.

Comment: I'm not looking to save current date but very specific date from calendar. Timestampable is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution. Since I've been working on a reference, the doctrine didn't see the change. The answer is to clone the object, and then modify it. Here is correct code:

```
public function moveAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $id = $request->get('id');
    $daydelta = $request->get('daydelta');
    $minutedelta = $request->get('minutedelta');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MedSystemTimetableBundle:Appointment')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Appointment entity.');
    }

        if (0 != $daydelta) {

        $day = ($daydelta > 0) ? '+'.$daydelta : $daydelta;
        $day .= (abs($daydelta) == 1) ? ' day' : ' days';

        $modifyFrom = clone $entity->getTimeFrom();
        $modifyTo = clone $entity->getTimeTo();

        $entity->setTimeFrom($modifyFrom->modify($day));
        $entity->setTimeTo($modifyTo->modify($day));
    }
    if (0 != $minutedelta) {

        $month = ($minutedelta > 0) ? '+'.$minutedelta : $minutedelta;
        $month .= (abs($minutedelta) == 1) ? ' minute' : ' minutes';

        $modifyFrom = clone $entity->getTimeFrom();
        $modifyTo = clone $entity->getTimeTo();        

        $entity->setTimeFrom($modifyFrom->modify($month));
        $entity->setTimeTo($test)->modify($month);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return new Response('ok', 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. And you're missing the persist. Just add before you `flush()`

```
$em->persist($entity);
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Persist is not required while updating entry. It is only required for creating new entry.